# In Terminal, what's the difference between “cd /” and “cd //”?

Tags: command-line, terminal, tilde

I don't understand the difference between these two. They both seem to take me to the root directory. Are there differences?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/105894

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Try "///////", it will work as well.

Comment: for example: if you try "cd /home", then "pwd",you will get "/home"; if you try "cd //home", then "pwd",you will get "//home". if you use "cd  //$path" ,that will cacuse "make" command error.